# Trying to monitor and limit the amount of bandwidth everyone uses (scenario inside)

Tags: networking

So lately this week, one rogue user from the boarding house has been downloading(possibly torrenting)/streaming to his/her heart's content resulting in extremely slow connections for everyone else. I've been using an Android app to list all devices connected to the network, and one-by-one, manually disconnected each one to find the problematic, bandwidth-hogging IP. I've found that said user continued to use up bandwidth even up to the wee hours of the morning.

I managed to find his/her IP address, I know I could just block sites/ports via the router's control panel but I guess it's not that simple because: a.) Whoever setup the wireless on our floor forgot the username/password combo(not even the landlady knows) b.) I've asked management about asking for access to the router, and they didn't understand a thing I was trying to tell them(mostly elderly folks with little/no computer knowledge.) Being the IT student on the floor, I guess I'll take the responsibility of at least limiting the rogue user's bandwidth so everyone else on our floor has a fair share.

So my question is: is there a way to limit an IP/application's bandwidth usage via a non-router control panel method, without having to do a hard reset on the router? I have tried in vain to use the Android app I used, but all it takes is a router reboot to disable it (said user knows how to reset the router). It's been days since we've had a stable connection for legitimate schoolwork usage because of this one IP that's using up all the resources. Hoping someone would be able to help me.

The router on our floor is a Linksys WRT54G2 and my operating system is Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: You may have some control from the QoS - http://www.publicvoid.dk/LinksysQualityOfServiceQoSSetupGuide.aspx

Comment: Have you tried the default user (blank) and password ("admin")?

Comment: Thanks for answering Dave! Unfortunately, as stated in my first post, I'm unable to get in through the router's administrator page to set QOS because a.) the one who set the router up forgot the password, b.) management cannot help because they do not know a thing about computers. I was hoping for something along the lines of a Windows application or the like. Thanks again!

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: Yes, I have. I've tried a bunch of possible combinations for the admin/router password from a site that lists the default values for most routers.

Comment: @Dominic - Why don't you [factory reset](http://technicallyeasy.net/2008/01/how-to-reset-linksys-wrt54g-wireless/) the router? That would reset the username and password, allowing you to access it with the default, as well as taking control of the router to prevent future problems. Edit: Just saw that you didn't want to do that, but any particular reason why? And is there no authority you can talk to besides building management?

Comment: Doing a hard reset isn't possible because the Router's fixed to a high ceiling. The other user could easily reboot the router because it has a reboot button on its top (which would be facing the floor from how it's placed) that's easily pushable with the use of a broom, but it's impossible to reach the small, pinhole-sized factory reset button (which I assume is on its underside or side).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use aircrack-ng to dis-associate that person from the wireless router. That would temporarily fix the bandwidth problem. Also you could set up a script to run the command over and over again to keep the person from even getting back on long enough to use it. [Here is a link to the documentation for this method](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=deauthentication).

another method would be to arp-poison and potentially dns-poison that particular users computer. [Here is a great guide on this type of MITM "method of control"](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Understanding-Man-in-the-Middle-Attacks-ARP-Part1.html).

Comment: since you are running windows 7 x64 the easiest method of getting all these "methods" working would be to download backtrack 5r3 vmware image and installing vmware player. everything you would need is already installed in backtrack.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll try this out as soon as I finish reading the articles.